# How to perform path queries in an unrooted tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, graph-algorithm

I have an unrooted tree, and given queries of form u and v. I am supposed to compute path queries from u to v, like give the sum of frequencies of weights along the path. I tried finding the lca in an unrooted tree but that got me nowhere, as lca is calculate with reference to a node. How do I go on to solve path queries in general operating on weights along the way in an unrooted tree?

Answer (score 0):

Choose any vertice as `root`.

Store path_sum of vertex from `root` for all vertices `O(n)` time.

> `value[x]` = path_sum to `x` from `root`

for query:

**query** (`a`, `b`) = `path_sum(root, a) + path_sum(root, b) - path_sum(root, lca)`

> `query(a, b) = value[a] + value[b] - value[lca]`